# S(p)-C(p) vs. O(p)-C(p) overlap

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, orbitals, periodic-trends

In Grossman, The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms, he provides the following explanation. The question asks to explain why the difference in pKa values between PhSH and EtSH is much smaller than PhOH and EtOH. In the solutions manual he writes:

[image: Grossman, The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms, EOC 1j]

- **Why is p orbital overlap dispositive for the strength of resonance stabilization exactly?** I don't get it.
- Furthermore, is this something I can simply take for granted about
  the size of atoms or **does this derive from a more general
  principle** about orbital overlap it would be useful to take forward?
  In other words, its there a way I may have deduced this from
  something else?
- **Could you show me any other and perhaps trickier examples where p orbital overlap modulates resonance structures in this way, in terms
  of size or otherwise?** I'm just always looking for more practice
  material that's out of my wheelhouse so I can get exposure. Thanks
  guys.

Comment: Umm, I think you should be less verbose and more *specific*. A bit formatting to highlight important parts, would be useful, at least.

Comment: In general, bigger p-block atoms tend to make weaker bonds, especially pi bonds. That's a rule of thumb. Well, maybe it's not taught properly, but that's beside the point, like any "how to know it in the first place"

Comment: There is no such book as "*The Art of Mechanisms*" written by Grossman.

Comment: @andselisk I believe he's referring to Grossman's "*The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms*", albeit in a contracted form.

Comment: @C_Lycoris I figured, but what's the point? A citation must be accurate and complete set of information, not a riddle.

Comment: @andselisk no opposition to that logic, at least not from me.

Comment: I agree with you guys too. Editing the answer now.